# how to remove several positions in an array

Tags: r

I want remove specific positions in an array (I saw similar question, but removing values, not the positions), and I'm having some problems. Let's say I have:

```
                  myval <- runif(1:1805)
                  pos   <- c(240,601,962,1323,1684)  #positions to remove
```

if I do:

```
                  myval[pos] <- NULL
```

it doesn't work..
And neither with

```
                  myval[myval!=myval[pos]]
```

Any suggestion??

Thanks!

Comment: `myval[-pos]` perhaps?

Comment: Great! thanks a lot, it was easier than expected :)

Comment: maybe the reading of [an introduction to R](http://cran.us.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) (for example) would have helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 myval <- runif(1:1805)
 pos   <- c(240,601,962,1323,1684) 

 myval2 <- myval[-c(240,601,962,1323,1684)]
```

Example:

```
myval <- runif(1:10)
pos   <- c(1,3,5) 
> myval
 [1] 0.07164492 0.86893169 0.39765225 0.29250478 0.44801653 0.87705892 0.13752579 0.86567680
 [9] 0.32595052 0.23871446


myval2 <- myval[-pos]

> myval2
[1] 0.8689317 0.2925048 0.8770589 0.1375258 0.8656768 0.3259505 0.2387145
```